# multiple formulas in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to generate a string of text from three columns. All columns are into one single excel sheet. like following ( The string i am showing here is just a dummy string, actual string is a **multi line xml** having values from column Value1, Value2, Value 3.

```
Value1  Value2  Value3            THE STRING
A         B       C     My string have < >, it also have < > , and look it has < > too
```

I was trying to have multiple formulas in one cell but i can't figure out if it is possible. The actual sheet will have several rows and i just want to drag the same for all of them to generate the string text.The generated string will look like "**My string have A, it also have B, and look it has C too**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I see what the problem is. What about this?

```
  | A   | B   | C     | D
1 | ONE | TWO | THREE | ="I have <" & A1 & "> and <" & B1 & "> and finally <" & C1 & ">"
```

Now, the content of cell D1 will be `I have <ONE> and <TWO> and finally <THREE>`.

If you don't like the `&` notation and prefer a full-blown Excel formula, you can use `=CONCATENATE`.

Comment: @pnuts: I realise that. But since the OP mentioned that *actual string is a multi line xml*, I thought I'd leave the angle brackets in there to demonstrate that this would work with such characters.